# Is it possible to use data tables to assign to a @Shared variable?

Tags: spock

I'm dealing with a series of tests which are pretty redundant, that assign a value to an inherited `@Shared` variable for use in successive test classes, like so:

```
def "test1"() {
    when:
        sharedVar1 = doSomething(10, 20)
    then:
        sharedVar1 > 0
}

def "test2"() {
    when:
        sharedVar2 = doSomething(3, 7)
    then:
        sharedVar2 > 0
}

...
```

There can be upwards of eight of these in a row, all doing exactly the same thing, just with different variables.

I attempted to make this simpler using `@Unroll` and data tables, like so:

```
@Unroll
def "test #n"() {
    when:
        localVar = doSomething(a, b)
    then:
        localVar > 0
    where:
        localVar   | a  | b  | n
        sharedVar1 | 10 | 20 | 1
        sharedVar2 | 3  | 7  | 2
        ...
}
```

But I've come across the (in hindsight) obvious problem where the assignment in the `when:` block is assigning the value to the *local* variable `localVar` and not the *shared* variable that I want to assign the value to.

Is there any simple way to use the data-table/data-pipe style of writing these tests that allows me to assign to the shared variables, or am I essentially limited to only using this style of testing when I *don't* need to assign values to shared variables?

Comment: You can use shared variables as sources in data tables, but not targets and what would be the point? Shared vars should be avoided if possible.

Comment: if you really want to use shared variables, would `when: sharedVar[n] = doSomething(a, b) then: sharedVar[n] > 0` work for you? you can then remove the first column of your where-table (i assume you can turn sharedVar1, sharedVar2 ... into a shared array)?